# How to rewrite config files using SNMP?

Tags: tools, exploit, network-scanners, routing

I scanned a router and found that the community string is public. The write access is also enabled. Now I want to change the configuration of the router. Can anybody tell me about tools and tutorials by which I can know how to change the configuration? Thanks in advance.

Comment: please provide more information, such as the brand, model and firmware of your router. I'm also thinking this may be more on topic over on serverfault.com - as it isn't a security question - but either way: more info please!

Answer (score 2):

[Cisco SNMP Tool](http://billythekids.demirdesign.com/) is a tool that allows you to:

- Telnet to Host
- Reboot device
- Upload Running & Startup Configuration
- Download Running & Startup Configuration
- Reset Passwords
- Write NVRAM

Just make sure you have permission before doing anything on the router.

Comment: This is not working for me. May be because the router is not from Cisco. Any other option please.

Answer (score 1):

SNMP uses "Set" and "Get" against MIB (Management Information Base) values to change and view information on managed devices.

If you get the MIB tree for the vendor of the router you are looking at and then use an SNMP tool along with the credentials you should be able to change the configuration of the MIB values supported.

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide us the manufacturer of the router before any specific help can be given.

The manufacturer's website should provide links and guides on how to do what you've asked.

Answer (score 0):

Solarwinds Orion platform is primarily a Monitoring solution however they have an engineers toolset which includes a tool call 'cisco config upload' when your device is managed by Solarwinds and Solarwinds knows of the read write SNMP string  configured on the device you can use this tool to push config to the device in question via SNMP.

You can either merge config with existing config or upload a whole new config. It's got me out of a few jams.

Have a look here http://www.solarwinds.com/engineers-toolset?&CMP=KNC-TAD-GGL-SW_NE_IE_PP_CPC_LD_EN_BRD_DWA-XPIL-X_X_X_X-X&kwid=gXBqWzbZ&gclid=CK3e3LPHyM8CFcy77QodbnIIVQ

You can get a 30 day eval licence to try it out. You have to download theOrion core module first so you can install engineers toolset on top of it.